# Adding a SQL constraint to same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm struggling on this one. My table looks like this:

```
name | slug | version
Hi   | hi   | 1
Hi   | hi   | 2
Bye  | bye  | 1
```

I want to add a constraint for the slug. Each time I "update" it inserts a new row for history with +1 to the version. I need to formate this the best way.

How do I build this constraint? keeps telling me it's incorrectly formed when I attempt to make one, but I'm new to this.

I guess the similar applies to blog comment table:

```
comment_id | parent | blog_id | comment
1          | 0      | 1       | nice work!
2          | 0      | 1       | great!
3          | 1      | 1       | yes, this is nice work!
```

The parent would be joined to comment_id, because it's a response to comment_id 1? Is this the same thing?

Comment: MySQL until version 8.0.16 doesn't support constraints so you would need to use a trigger instead [(reference)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html).

Comment: @nick how is that done? I'm super new to optimising tables.

Comment: First, MySQL is not SQL Server - solutions of this nature tend to be highly specific to your database engine so **tag correctly**. Second, a constraint does not create or assign values - it **constrains** (limits) the domain of values that can be stored within a row. So you have chosen the wrong path already. Lastly, don't confuse things by trying to solve the same problem with different tables. First step is to post DDL and a simple script that reproduces your issue.